# git alias: Parameter doesn't work

Tags: git, parameters, git-alias

I figured out that `git branch | grep <something> | cut -d' ' -f2` will give me the name of a branch that contains the substring `<something>`. I'm trying to put this command in a git alias, like so:

```
[alias]
    gb = "!f(){ git branch | grep $1 | cut -d' ' -f2; };f"
    # ...
```

However, this does not work; it just produces a blank line. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you by chance searching for a branch that is not your current branch, in which case there is no '*' at the beginning of the line, which throws off your `cut` options? If so, try using `awk '{print $NF}'` instead of your `cut` invocation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by the commenter above, the fix is to use `awk '{print $NF}'` instead of the `cut` command.